# Haskell 32 to 64 bit cross compilation

Tags: linux, haskell, cross-compiling

I only have a x86_**32** machine running Linux. On this machine I coded a small Haskell program.

Now I need to provide a x86_**64** Linux binary.

Which is the easiest / less painful way to achieve that?

Comment: You can try passing `-optc "-m64"` if your GHC is set up to compile through GCC...

Answer (score 4):

Borrow or rent (e.g. EC2) an x86_64 machine for long enough to compile your program. The latter would cost on the order of $0.01.

If this is not possible, then assuming you have a C cross-compiler to x86_64, you can try following the directions at https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/CrossCompiling. However, as far as I know nobody has tried this before and I would be surprised if there are no bugs lurking for the case when the compiler's `Int` size is smaller than the target platform's word size.

Comment: Or, if you prefer to do everything locally, just start a [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) instance with a 32 bit OS. It won't be the fastest, but certainly quite easy.

Comment: @gspr you mean a 64-bit OS I think, but yes it certainly sounds easier than trying to cross-compile.